# Using www at 2nd level subdomain ignores the 1st level subdomain in apartment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, subdomain, apartment-gem

I have subdomains like: `lks.harabiz.com` & `lkm.harabiz.com`, each with its own database tables.

When somebody tries the URL: `www.lkm.harabiz.com`, the database tables being used are different from `lkm`'s, and those database tables actually belong to `www`, not to `lkm`.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Point `www.lkm.harabiz.com` to simply `lkm.harabiz.com`.
2. Make `www.lkm.harabiz.com` use the database tables that actually belong to `lkm`, and not to `www`.

I'm using Rails 5.0.0.1, and the app is deployed through Heroku.

I have looked the DNS stuff, plus stuff on application level, but I'm unable to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Custom Elevator](https://github.com/influitive/apartment#custom-elevator):

```
# application.rb
module MyApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::Generic, Proc.new { |request| request.host.split('.')[-3] }
  end
end
```

Comment: It works. But is there a way I could be able to remove the 2nd level subdomain altogether?

Comment: Also, this custom elevator doesn't work if the subdomain is `www`.

Comment: If you want to redirect `www.lkm.harabiz.com` to `lkm.harabiz.com`, you can do it via DNS or nginx/apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Simply increase [Top Level Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) by 1:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 2
end
```

More information about this option is there: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

And there's a little description about how it works: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html

Answer (score 0):

you can trap from your config/routes.rb file with this code below

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '', to: 'lkm_controllers#index', constraints: lambda { |r|
   r.subdomain.present? && r.subdomain == "www.lkm"
  }
  get '', to: 'lks_controllers#index', constraints: lambda { |r|
   r.subdomain.present? && r.subdomain == "www.lks"
  }
  # other resources
end
```

make sure these 2 commands you put above, so it checked it first whether it's using www.lkm or just lkm

Answer (score 0):

The way to use those different tables is application specific, so you shouldnt add any DNS interaction code because it will make your code fragile and less portable, NOR modify DNS options in heroku or your DNS entries.

What you need is to make use your desired database based on the host of the HTTP request arriving your app. Look at `Rails.application.routes` and https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/AbstractRequest/request_uri to do it. Read about request routing for your framework. (or put here your routing code to get more help)

Answer (score 0):

Change the apartment gem configuration and add 'www' to exclude_domains
in `config/initializers/apartment/subdomain_exclusions.rb`:

```
Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain.excluded_subdomains = ['www']
```